# Trying to write a script for an autoemail, but it keeps saying there is a SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token line: 12 file: Parent Email.gs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have my fill out a google form and have it autogenerate emails to parents.  Here is the code, I keep getting a syntax error.  Help?

```
function emailFormToParent(e) {
var studentName = e.values[1];
var parentName = e.values[2];
var parentEmail = e.values[3];
var generalclass = e.values[4];
var assignments = e.values[5];
var assessments = e.values[6];
var actionplan = e.values[7];

var emailSubject = "Monthly Parent Email " + studentName;
var emailBody = " ";
emailBody += "Dear " + parentName + “\n”;
emailBody += general class + “.\n”;
emailBody += assignments + “.\n”;
emailBody += assessments  + “\n”;
emailBody += actionplan + “.\n”;
emailBody += “Sincerely,\n” + studentName;
MailApp.sendEmail(parentEmail, emailSubject, emailBody, {cc: ‘myemail’})
}
```

Comment: It could be that you have `”` characters in your code instead of `"` characters. There is a slight difference between those two.

Comment: You also have a space between "general" and "class" instead of `generalclass`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing all the quotes to normal quotation characters (`"` and `'`) and try removing the space, as indicated below.

```js
function emailFormToParent(e) {
    var studentName = e.values[1];
    var parentName = e.values[2];
    var parentEmail = e.values[3];
    var generalclass = e.values[4];
    var assignments = e.values[5];
    var assessments = e.values[6];
    var actionplan = e.values[7];

    var emailSubject = 'Monthly Parent Email ' + studentName;
    var emailBody = ' ';
    emailBody += 'Dear ' + parentName + '\n';
    emailBody += generalclass + '.\n'; // <============= this line was "general class" with a space
    emailBody += assignments + '.\n';
    emailBody += assessments + '\n';
    emailBody += actionplan + '.\n';
    emailBody += 'Sincerely,\n' + studentName;
    MailApp.sendEmail(parentEmail, emailSubject, emailBody, { cc: 'myemail' });
}
```